# Same wordpress installation different subdomain

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to access the same wordpress website
from servel domains for ex:

```
www.example.com
sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
```

I've downloaded the "Domain mirror" plugin and Installed it and also configured it.

```
$default_options['domain_1'] = '';
$default_options['blogname_1'] = 'example';         // Weblog Title
$default_options['blogdescription_1'] = '';     // Tagline
$default_options['siteurl_1'] = 'http://example.com';       // Wordpress Address
$default_options['home_1'] = 'http://example.com';          // Blog Address

$default_options['domain_2'] = 'a';
$default_options['blogname_2'] = '';
$default_options['blogdescription_2'] = '';
$default_options['siteurl_2'] = 'http://sub1.example.com';
$default_options['home_2'] = 'http://sub1.example.com';


$default_options['domain_3'] = 'b';
$default_options['blogname_3'] = '';
$default_options['blogdescription_3'] = '';
$default_options['siteurl_3'] = 'http://sub2.example.com';
$default_options['home_3'] = 'http://sub2.example.com';
```

But when I enter the website from my subdomains sub1, sub2.
all the links redirect to http://example.com/....
instead of http://sub1.example.com/... or http://sub2.example.com/...

Comment: This should be a question for the `Domain Mirror` plugin developers, but I think the redirection is correct. I think that's the idea, redirecting everything to a single location, otherwise ¿what would be the purpose of redirecting, in the first place? Redirecting does not mean that you will have 3 sites instead of one. Hope I understood right your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this plugin doesn't work for new wordpress versions.. since its really old.
anyway, I managed to fix it by adding

```
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define('WP_SITEURL',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

to my wp-config.
:)